# How can I import multiple Python modules into one Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, import, module, window

How can I import multiple Python modules which contain different parts of a Tkinter window.

I have created a Tkinter window inside a Python class. This Python class also contains multiple different Tkinter widgets. I have then imported the module into my main Python file and run the code. This has worked as expected and the Tkinter window was correctly displayed.

I then imported a Python module from inside a different Python file. When I run this code, I receive the error message: type object 'window' has no attribute 'tk'.

I understand that this is because the new Python file cannot find the Tkinter window. However, I am unable to fix this issue.

If possible, I do not want to create the Tkinter window in the main Python file. I also do not want to add both classes to the same Python file, in order to keep my code clean.

An example of my code:

Python file containing the module to create the Tkinter window:

```
from tkinter import *

class createWindowAndAddWidgets:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window

    def createWindow(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Title of the window")

def addWidgets(self):
    myFrame = Frame(self.window, bg="#a1b8e1")
    myFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

def showWindow(self):
    self.window.mainloop()
```

Python file containing the other widgets

```
from tkinter import *
from file_to_create_window import createWindowAndAddWidgets

class other_widgets:
    def the_other_widgets(self):
        myOtherFrame = Frame(self.window, bg="#1e8b1a")
        myOtherFrame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
```

Main Python file

```
from file_to_create_window import createWindowAndAddWidgets
from file_to_create_other_widgets import other_widgets

myWindow = window()
myWindow.createWindow()
myWindow.addWidgets()
myWindow.other_widgets()
myWindow.showWindow()
```

As you can see from the above example, I have 3 Python files. The first file contains a class which creates the window and adds some widgets to the window. The second file contains a class which adds other widgets to the window. The third file is supposed to run the classes and produce the output. However, I receive the error message: type object 'window' has no attribute 'tk'. I recieve this error on Line 6 of the Python fle contining the other widgets:  `myOtherFrame = Frame(self.window, bg="#1e8b1a")`

Comment: Add `self` to `def __init__(self,..`

Comment: I suggest you to go through some tutorials on Python class to understand more on class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create an instance of the class before calling it.

For example:

```
from file_to_create_window import createWindowAndAddWidgets
from file_to_create_other_widgets import other_widgets

myWindow = window()
myWindow.createWindow()
myWindow.addWidgets()

otherWidgetsWindow = file_to_create_other_widgets()
otherWidgetsWindow.other_widgets()
myWindow.showWindow()
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited: Update function to prevent duplicated window.

You cannot add all of them. Use prefix `window.`

```
myWindow.createWindow()
myWindow.addWidgets()
myWindow.other_widgets()
myWindow.showWindow()
```

file_to_create_window.py

```
class createWindowAndAddWidgets:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window         
        self.createWindow()
         

    def createWindow(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Title of the window")
        self.addWidgets()
         
        

    def addWidgets(self):
        myFrame = Frame(self.window, bg="#a1b8e1")
        myFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.showWindow()

    def showWindow(self):
        self.window.mainloop()
```

file_to_create_window.py

```
from file_to_create_window import createWindowAndAddWidgets
import tkinter as tk
 

myWindow = createWindowAndAddWidgets(tk)
myWindow.createWindow()
```